# What does a fullstop or period or dot (.) mean in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, syntax, operators, function-composition

I really wish that Google was better at searching for syntax:

```
decades         :: (RealFrac a) => a -> a -> [a] -> Array Int Int
decades a b     =  hist (0,9) . map decade
                   where decade x = floor ((x - a) * s)
                         s        = 10 / (b - a)
```

Comment: A period can also be a namespace separator (e.g. `Data.Vector.Unboxed.length`).

Comment: For searching for information about Haskell code, I heartily recommend Hoogle (http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/), a search engine for types (e.g. searching for `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` turns up `map`) and function/operator names (so searching for `map` turns up `map`, and searching for `.` turns up the Prelude function composition operator `(.)`).  There's also Hayoo! (http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html), which has less of an emphasis on types but indexes more packages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dot Operator in Haskell: need more explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631284/dot-operator-in-haskell-need-more-explanation)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`f(g(x))`

is

in mathematics : `f ∘ g` `(x)`

in haskell :  `( f . g )` `(x)`

Answer (score 19):

It means function composition.
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631284/dot-operator-in-haskell-need-more-explanation).

Note also the `f.g.h x` is not equivalent to `(f.g.h) x`, because it is interpreted as `f.g.(h x)` which won't typecheck unless (h x) returns a function.

This is where the $ operator can come in handy: `f.g.h $ x` turns x from being a parameter to `h` to being a parameter to the whole expression. And so it becomes equivalent to `f(g(h x))` and the pipe works again.

Comment: You just need to remember that the function application operator (space) has the highest priority. After some time it will all make sense.

Answer (score 14):

`.` is a higher order function for function composition.

```
Prelude> :type (.)
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
Prelude> (*2) . (+1) $ 1
4
Prelude> ((*2) . (+1)) 1
4
```

Answer (score 6):

"The period is a function composition operator. In general terms, where f  and g are functions, (f . g) x means the same as f (g x). In other words, the period is used to take the result from the function on the right, feed it as a parameter to the function on the left, and return a new function that represents this computation."

Comment: 12 years later this SO question is the first result

Answer (score 3):

It is a function composition: [link](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#composition)

Answer (score 2):

[Function composition](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/functions.html) (the page is pretty long, use search)

Comment: Better suited as a comment.