# What does the . do in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does a fullstop or period or dot (.) mean in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486564/what-does-a-fullstop-or-period-or-dot-mean-in-haskell)

This is such a general question, but I actually don't know why it's there. If you have like: sort.function    what does the . actually do? or mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does a fullstop or period or dot (.) mean in Haskell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486564/what-does-a-fullstop-or-period-or-dot-mean-in-haskell) and [Dot Operator in Haskell: need more explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631284/dot-operator-in-haskell-need-more-explanation)

Answer (score 2):

Function composition.

`(f . g) x` is the same as `f (g x)`