# Trying to understand the dot operator

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to understand how the dot operator works. Here's an example:

```
main = do
    ns <- getNetworkInterfaces
    mapM_ (putStr . showInterface) ns
```

I know that `mapM_` accepts a function and `Monad`. "ns" is a `Monad`. But how actually the part `(putStr . showInterface)` works in terms of Haskell grammar or syntax in this particular example? Once again: in this particular example. Also, which function will be called first: putStr or showInterface?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631284/dot-operator-in-haskell-need-more-explanation , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486564/what-does-a-fullstop-or-period-or-dot-mean-in-haskell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's just composition - it does one after the other (from the right) - so

```
(putStr . showInterface) n
```

is just

```
putStr (showInterface n)
```

so in a sense `showInterface` is *called first*

---

please note that your understanding is a bit flawed here - `ns` is not the monad here that matters (it's a list - it's the `Foldable` part in the newer versions of `mapM_`) - the monad that matters is `IO` and `mapM_` accepts a monadic action and a list of things to put into that action (one by one) - so here every item in `ns` is put into the action

```
putStr . showInterface
```

and of course each one will first be used int the *pure* function `showInterface` (which obviously produces a string) and then be printed to `stdout` using `putStr` (**this** is the monadic action that *needs* the `mapM_`)

---

### if in *doubt* check the signature

If you want to find out which part *matters* look at the signature

In case of `mapM_` it's:

```
mapM_ :: (Monad m, Foldable t) => (a -> m b) -> t a -> m ()
```

forget the `Foldable t` here - it's your list:

```
mapM_ :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m ()
```

now what can the `m` be?

Well you use `putStr . showInterface` for the first argument - now I don't know exactly what `showInterface` is - but as you compose it with `putStr` the resulting type should be something like

```
putStr . showInterface :: SomeInterfaceType -> IO ()
```

and now you should see that: `m ~ IO`, `a ~ SomeInterfaceType` and `b ~ ()` - notice that the **monad** is `IO`! - and you get:

```
mapM_ (putStr . showInterface) :: [SomeInterfaceType] -> IO ()
```

Comment: list is a Monad, isn't it?

Comment: yes it is - but the one that matters here is the `IO` monad - do make list the one that matters you would need a action of type `a -> [b]` - try and play with `mapM (\x -> [x,x]) (Just 5)` do see the difference with a different `Foldable` (`Maybe` in this case) as well

Comment: To get a better feel for how list as a monad works, try `mapM (\x -> [x, -x]) [1,2,3]`, compared to `map (\x -> [x,-x]) [1,2,3]`. (IMO, the example mapping over a `Maybe` hides the nondeterministic interpretation of the list monad that `mapM` allows.)

Comment: @chepner yes - but so you can mistake the monad and the foldable again ;)

Comment: We need a bigger, non-list traversable, like a tree :)