# In Haskell, how do you trim whitespace from the beginning and end of a string?

Tags: string, haskell, trim, removing-whitespace

How do you trim whitespace from the start and end of a string?

```
trim "  abc " 

=>

"abc"
```

Edit:

Ok, let me be a little clearer. I did not understand that string literals were treated so differently from Strings.

I would like to do this:

```
import qualified Data.Text as T
let s :: String = "  abc  "
in T.strip s
```

Is this possible in Haskell? I am using -XOverloadedStrings but that appears only to work for literals.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If you have serious text processing needs then use the `text` package from hackage:

```
> :set -XOverloadedStrings
> import Data.Text
> strip "  abc   "
"abc"
```

If you're too stubborn to use `text` and don't like the inefficiency of the reverse method then perhaps (and I mean MAYBE) something like the below will be more efficient:

```
import Data.Char

trim xs = dropSpaceTail "" $ dropWhile isSpace xs

dropSpaceTail maybeStuff "" = ""
dropSpaceTail maybeStuff (x:xs)
        | isSpace x = dropSpaceTail (x:maybeStuff) xs
        | null maybeStuff = x : dropSpaceTail "" xs
        | otherwise       = reverse maybeStuff ++ x : dropSpaceTail "" xs


> trim "  hello this \t should trim ok.. .I  think  ..  \t "
"hello this \t should trim ok.. .I  think  .."
```

I wrote this on the assumption that the length of spaces would be minimal, so your O(n) of `++` and `reverse` is of little concern. But once again I feel the need to say that if you actually are concerned about the performance then you shouldn't be using `String` at all - move to `Text`.

EDIT making my point, a quick Criterion benchmark tells me that (for a particularly long string of words with spaces and ~200 pre and post spaces) my trim takes 1.6 ms, the trim using reverse takes 3.5ms, and `Data.Text.strip` takes 0.0016 ms...

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I convinced my team to add text to the project and it is saving a lot of headaches.

Comment: +1 for the benchmark it is great when people really prove their claims

Answer (score 53):

From: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trim_(programming)#Haskell

```
import Data.Char (isSpace)

trim :: String -> String
trim = f . f
   where f = reverse . dropWhile isSpace
```

Comment: And it is the simplest. For a quick-and-dirty use case, this is nice.

Comment: This is beautiful, although I would have used a `let` binding.

Answer (score 47):

After this question was asked (circa 2012) `Data.List` got `dropWhileEnd` making this a lot easier:

```
trim = dropWhileEnd isSpace . dropWhile isSpace
```

Comment: For those getting confused by the dot operator (used for function composition), this is equivalent of `trim :: String -> String` `trim xs = dropWhile isSpace (dropWhileEnd isSpace xs)`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631284/dot-operator-in-haskell-need-more-explanation http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:dropWhileEnd

Comment: For beginners (like me): This solution require that you first `import Data.List` and `import Data.Char`.

Comment: If one really wants to avoid importing anything, this one works too:
```trimall = dropWhile (`elem` " \t") . (reverse . dropWhile (`elem` " \t") . reverse)```
Which is a combination of the above answer and Simon Michael's below.

Answer (score 16):

Inefficient but easy to understand and paste in where needed:

```
strip = lstrip . rstrip
lstrip = dropWhile (`elem` " \t")
rstrip = reverse . lstrip . reverse
```

Answer (score 3):

For sure, Data.Text is better for performance. But, as was mentioned, it's just fun to do it with lists. Here is a version that rstrip's the string in single pass (without reverse and ++) and supports infinite lists:

```
rstrip :: String -> String
rstrip str = let (zs, f) = go str in if f then [] else zs
    where
        go [] = ([], True)
        go (y:ys) =
            if isSpace y then
                let (zs, f) = go ys in (y:zs, f)
            else
                (y:(rstrip ys), False)
```

p.s. as for infinite lists, that will work:

```
List.length $ List.take n $ rstrip $ cycle "abc  "
```

and, for obvious reason, that will not (will run forever):

```
List.length $ List.take n $ rstrip $ 'a':(cycle " ")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can combine `Data.Text`'s `strip` with it's un/packing functions to avoid having overloaded strings:

```hs
import qualified Data.Text as T

strip  = T.unpack . T.strip . T.pack
lstrip = T.unpack . T.stripStart . T.pack
rstrip = T.unpack . T.stripEnd . T.pack
```

Testing it:

```hs
> let s = "  hello  "
> strip s
"hello"
> lstrip s
"hello  "
> rstrip s
"  hello"
```

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays the `MissingH` package ships with a [`strip`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MissingH-1.4.0.1/docs/Data-String-Utils.html#v:strip) function:

```
import           Data.String.Utils

myString = "    foo bar    "
-- strip :: String -> String
myTrimmedString = strip myString
-- myTrimmedString == "foo bar"
```

So if the conversion from `String` to `Text` and back does not make sense in your situation, you could use the function above.

Comment: I get "Could not find module ‘Data.String.Utils’"

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I saw no solutions that implemented good old `fold`.

First strip the leading white-space using `dropWhile`. Then, using `foldl'` and a simple closure, you can analyze the rest of the string in one pass, and based on that analysis, pass that informative parameter to `take`, without needing `reverse`:

```
import Data.Char (isSpace)
import Data.List (foldl')

trim :: String -> String
trim s = let
  s'    = dropWhile isSpace s
  trim' = foldl'
            (\(c,w) x -> if isSpace x then (c,w+1)
                         else (c+w+1,0)) (0,0) s'
  in
   take (fst trim') s'
```

Variable `c` keeps track of combined white and non white-space that should be absorbed, and variable `w` keeps track of right side white-space to be stripped.

Test Runs:

```
print $ trim "      a   b c    "
print $ trim "      ab c    "
print $ trim "    abc    "
print $ trim "abc"
print $ trim "a bc    "
```

Output:

```
"a   b c"
"ab c"
"abc"
"abc"
"a bc"
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be right about O(n), I believe:

```
import Data.Char (isSpace)

trim :: String -> String
-- Trimming the front is easy. Use a helper for the end.
trim = dropWhile isSpace . trim' []
  where
    trim' :: String -> String -> String
    -- When finding whitespace, put it in the space bin. When finding
    -- non-whitespace, include the binned whitespace and continue with an
    -- empty bin. When at the end, just throw away the bin.
    trim' _ [] = []
    trim' bin (a:as) | isSpace a = trim' (bin ++ [a]) as
                     | otherwise = bin ++ a : trim' [] as
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about the runtime or efficiency but what about this:

```
-- entirely input is to be trimmed
trim :: String -> String
trim = Prelude.filter (not . isSpace')

-- just the left and the right side of the input is to be trimmed
lrtrim :: String -> String
lrtrim = \xs -> rtrim $ ltrim xs
  where
    ltrim = dropWhile (isSpace')
    rtrim xs
      | Prelude.null xs = []
      | otherwise = if isSpace' $ last xs
                    then rtrim $ init xs
                    else xs 

-- returns True if input equals ' '
isSpace' :: Char -> Bool
isSpace' = \c -> (c == ' ')
```

A solution without using any other module or library than the Prelude.

Some tests:

```
>lrtrim ""
>""

>lrtrim "       "
>""

>lrtrim "haskell       "
>"haskell"

>lrtrim "      haskell       "
>"haskell"

>lrtrim "     h  a  s k e   ll       "
>"h  a  s k e   ll"
```

It could be runtime O(n).

But I actually don't know it because I don't know the runtimes of the functions last and init. ;)

Comment: Both are O(n), though init has at least a factor of two over last, since it copies n - 1 elements.  Use Data.Text for this kind of thing.  Making your own with Prelude functions is easy and fun and slow.

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of what other people have suggested, you can avoid having to reverse your string by using:

```
import Data.Char (isSpace)

dropFromTailWhile _ [] = []
dropFromTailWhile p item
  | p (last items) = dropFromTailWhile p $ init items
  | otherwise      = items

trim :: String -> String
trim = dropFromTailWhile isSpace . dropWhile isSpace
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to implement your own `trim` function without importing any fancy packages.

```hs
import Data.Char (isSpace)

trimLeft :: String -> String
trimLeft = dropWhile isSpace

trimRight :: String -> String
trimRight = dropWhileEnd isSpace

trim :: String -> String
trim = trimRight . trimLeft
```

Answer (score -3):

Another (std) solution

```
import System.Environment
import Data.Text

strip :: String -> IO String
strip = return . unpack . Data.Text.strip . pack

main = getLine >>= Main.strip >>= putStrLn
```

Comment: why would you voluntarily wrap your result in `IO`?

Comment: Unnecessarily wrapping result in a monad sets a bad example, don't do that.