# Why don't the Data.Text examples work for me?

Tags: haskell

Here's what I tried to do in ghci:

```
import Data.Text
strip "  abc  "
```

I get this error message:

```
<interactive>:1:6:
    Couldn't match expected type `Text' against inferred type `[Char]'
    In the first argument of `strip', namely `"  abc  "'
    In the expression: strip "  abc  "
    In the definition of `it': it = strip "  abc  "
```

I was expecting this to work because it was given on many web pages including this answer: [In Haskell, how do you trim whitespace from the beginning and end of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270324/in-haskell-how-do-you-trim-whitespace-from-the-beginning-and-end-of-a-string/6270382#6270382)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You'll need to enable [overloaded string literals](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#overloaded-strings) in order to use string literals as `Text` values (otherwise string literals will always have the type `String = [Char]`).

Without overloaded string literals, you'll have to use `pack` to create a `Text` from a `String`, so:

```
strip $ pack "  abc  "
```

Comment: Overloaded strings are easiest to enable by adding the pragma to the first line of your .hs file: `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}`

Answer (score 11):

You should either start ghci using `ghci -XOverloadedStrings` or, if you are already in ghci and don't want to exit, set the flag dynamically using `:set -XOverloadedStrings`.

Answer (score 0):

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fwarn-missing-signatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Text as MJ

main :: IO()
main = do

      print $ strip $ pack "  abc  "
      print  $ MJ.intercalate "as" ["1","2","3"]
```

Comment: I will try and improve on my formatting - the above is an example of a working .hs file using ghc options as identified with {-# text #-} .